# Flex chart - Don't want all the information to be show

Tags: apache-flex, time, range, charts

In a Flex object I have this line chart that displays data from a arraycolection of arrays with date(x) price(y).
This is the code I'm using to implement this:

```
<s:DropDownList id="timeScale" change="timeScale_changeHandler(event)">
 <s:dataProvider>
  <s:ArrayCollection>
   <fx:String id="seconds">Segundos</fx:String>
   <fx:String id="minutes">Minutos</fx:String>
   <fx:String id="hours">Horas</fx:String>       
  </s:ArrayCollection>          
 </s:dataProvider>     
</s:DropDownList>
<mx:LineChart id="lineChart" dataProvider="{googleStore}" width="300" height="200" showDataTips="true">
 <mx:horizontalAxis>      
  <mx:DateTimeAxis id="xAxis" parseFunction=""/>      
 </mx:horizontalAxis>
 <mx:verticalAxis>
  <mx:LinearAxis id="rangeDefiner" />
 </mx:verticalAxis>
 <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>  
  <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{xAxis}" visible="true" showLabels="true" />   
 </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
 <mx:series>
  <mx:LineSeries displayName="Preço" yField="Price" xField="Date" />   
 </mx:series>
</mx:LineChart>
<mx:Legend dataProvider="{lineChart}"/>
```

The data set used to fill this chart is refreshed from 5 to 5 seconds.
What I want to be able to do is show information from minute to minute or hor t

Answer (score 0):

You should use the dataUnits="minutes" attribute for the DateTimeAxis incase you want to user to see the data with labels for each minute.

dataUnits="hours" for hourly granularity.